# How can I solve this equation for the exponent n?

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve:

$$(a^{n-5/2}-b^{n-5/2})=c$$

for $n$? $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known constant.

It seems that `Solve` cannot solve it and `Reduce` goes on forever and never produces an output.

`a=1/6`, `b=0.0057` `c=15952.6`

Comment: What's known about `a,b,c`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have edited the post to add the values of the constants.

Comment: There is no analytical solution to this question in general. It is of the form $A^n - B^n = C$. Need to solve it numerically.

Comment: Try `Plot[lhs-rhs,{n,...}]` your equation and you'll see there is no solution with given values of constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NMinimize` doesn't find a solution for your equation:

```
a = 1/6
b = 0.0057
c = 15952.6
NMinimize[{(a^(n - 5/2) - b^ (n - 5/2) - c)^2}, n]
(*{2.54474*10^8, {n -> 2.81377}}*)
```